# Asynchronous behavior testing akka

Tags: scala, testing, akka, scalatest

### How can I test asynchronous behavior in akka?

I want to test an behavior that gets a message and then spawns a new behavior (I wanna make sure the behavior was spawned)

First I thought about using BehaviorTestKit (and .expectEffectType) but it doesn't work because its synchronous.

What should I do?

Comment: does the behavior make any interaction with the other behavior? or simply it creates the new actor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know from your "Spawner" Actor if it had spawned your "Worker" Behavior, send it back to "Reply" ActorRef.

maybe like:

```scala
/// BEHAVIOR case DoSomeStaff(replyTo) => replyTo ! Spawned(ctx.spawn(BEHAVIOR_WORKER, NAME))

val spawner = ctx.spawn(BEHAVIOR, "spawner")

val replyTo = TestInbox[Spawned]()

spawner ! API.DoSomeStuff(replyTo) <-- will send a ActorRef of Spawned Actor to ReplyTo

inbox.expectMessage("REF"...)
```